# How do I create my own snippets under $home/vimfiles/after in windows

Tags: windows, vim, snipmate

I am trying to create my own set of snippets for vim on Windows.

As soon as I create the directory `$HOME/vimfiles/after/snippets` (with or without files) the "standard" snippets (i.e. those that came with snipmate itself) won't be triggered anymore.

I have tried the same on a Linux installation where I was able to create a (working) set of snippets in `~/.vim/after/snippets/*.snippets`.

What am I missing?

**Edit** An answer asked if I am using the original snipmate or the fork?

Answer: I was unaware of such a fork and I seem to be using the "original" one.

**Edit II** `echo &rtp` contains `C:\Users\Rene/vimfiles/after` (under which I created the `snippets` directory).

Could it be that the mixed forward backward slashes is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What SnipMate are you talking about? [The original](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) or [the fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate)? The fork doesn't come with default snippets so you are certainly talking about the original, right?

`:help snipmate` says:

> Snippets are by default looked for any 'snippets' directory in your
>   'runtimepath'.

It's possible (but unlikely) that `after` is not part of your `runtimepath`… could you check with `:echo &rtp`?

Anyway, you can use the `g:snippets_dir` variable to tell SnipMate where to look for snippets:

```
let g:snippets_dir = '~/.vim/after/snippets/'
```